# If the straight lines $3x − y = −2$ and $ax + 2y = 3$ are parallel, then $a$ equals?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> i. If the straight lines $3x − y = −2$ and $ax + 2y = 3$ are parallel, then $a$ is equal to what?
>
> ii. If the straight lines $5x + y − 3 = 0$ and $bx − y − 2 = 0$ are perpendicular, then $b$ is equal to what?

I am confused with these. I'm not even sure where to start? Any advice/help?

Thank you.

Comment: What does being parallel (or perpendicular) mean in terms of the slope?

Comment: The product of two gradients equals -1?

Comment: That is true for the perpendicular case. So find the gradients of each line, multiply and set equal to $-1$. Solve for $b$. What about the parallel case?

Comment: For parallel the gradients are the same

Comment: So find both gradients and set them equal and that allows you to solve for $a$.

Comment: ii. Then it is -5 * x = -1 --> x = 1/5 --> b = 1/5 which is correct. Thank you but I am still stuck on i.

Comment: For i. I got m = 3 and -1/2

Comment: Almost. Check the second gradient. It should involve $a$. I've posted a solution with some details hidden.

Comment: I know, it say -a/2. But I just wrote it as that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i. If the straight lines $3x − y = −2$ and $ax + 2y = 3$ are parallel, then $a$ is equal to what?

**Hint:** 
First, and for the sake of simplicity, write $3x-y=-2$ as: $$y=\color{blue}3x+2\tag{1}$$ and $ax+2y=3$ as $$y=\color{blue}{-\dfrac a2}x+\dfrac32 \tag{ 2}.$$ We can now clearly determine the slopes (*gradients*) of the two lines from just looking at the coefficients of $x$ in $\text{(1)}$ and $\text{(2)}$ which turns out to be $m=3$ and $m'={-a/2}$.

Next, use this property:

> Let the line $(\rm D)$ be defined by the equation: $y=mx+b$ and the line $(\rm \Delta)$ be defined by the equation: $y=m'x+b'$.
>
> If $(\rm D)$ is parallel  to $(\Delta)$ then $m= m'$ and the opposite is true.

So you'll end up with the equation: $$3=-\dfrac a2$$
Solve it, and here is the value of $a$.

---

> ii. If the straight lines $5x + y − 3 = 0$ and $bx − y − 2 = 0$ are perpendicular, then $b$ is equal to what?

**Hint:** 
 Again, for the sake of simplicity we will reduce $5x+y-3=0$ to $$y=\color{blue}{-5}x+3\tag{3}$$ and the equation $bx-y-2=0$ to $$y=\color{blue}{b}x-2\tag{4}$$

So the slopes of the two lines are $m=-5$ and $m'=b$ respectively.

Now that we have the slopes (*gradients*), will use this property:

> Let the line $(\rm D)$ be defined by the equation: $y=mx+b$ and the line $(\rm \Delta)$ be defined by the equation: $y=m'x+b'$.
>
> If $(\rm D)$ is perpendicular to $(\Delta)$ then $m\cdot m'=-1$ and the opposite is true.

Therefore we have: $$-5\cdot b=-1.$$

Now, solve the equation and here is your value of $b$!

Answer (score 1):

In part (i), the gradients are $3$ and $-\frac{a}{2}$, respectively. Since they are parallel, you can set them equal and solve. This yields

> $-\dfrac{a}{2} = 3\\ a = -6$

In part (ii), the gradients are $-5$ and $b$, respectively. Since they are perpendicular, their product is $-1$. This yields

> $-5*b = -1 \\ b = \dfrac{-1}{-5} = \dfrac{1}{5}$

Comment: Thank you that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

The key to this problem deals with the slopes of perpendicular and parallel lines.

> **Hint:** one of them has something to do with a "negative reciprocal," or a product being equal to $-1$.  That may help you in looking through your notes.

Use algebra to convert the equations to slope-intercept ($y=mx+b$) form, then use the relationships between slopes to find the variables you seek.